# passing auth token as header format from client to remote server

Tags: android, android-volley, response

JSON response from a remote server

```
 {"status":"success",
"data":{"auth_token":"9389e656c90e11c451443657c8e",
"user":{"active_location":" Airport"}}}
```

I need to store the `auth_token`  and pass to the remote server as the header, 
tried `addHeader("key1", "value1");`
but still not working, need help

Comment: Couldn't understand what you need

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: actually need to store the auth token in client side and again need to send the auth token to remote server as header format

Comment: I am using volley library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send headers for belly request, you need to override getHeaders() method. Inside method create a map and put your key-value pairs and return the the map.

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(requestMethod, yourUrl, postData(if any), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        //TODO parse your response
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    //TODO handle error
    }
}){
    //Here is the place where you can add your headers
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("key1", "value1");
        return params;
    }
  };
```

Also if you need to pass any request parameters you can do that in the same way by overriding getParams() method.

For more details [check the volley tutorial](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Base64 to encode the token string and put it in SharedPrefs, then read and decode to send in a header.

Comment: no need for base64, since the authtoken does not represent a binary file. auth tokens usually only use characters [0-9a-e]

Comment: help  me with the syntax of sending the auth_token as header from client side to remote server

Comment: I'd like to help you here, but I haven't worked with Volley in years. Maybe have a look at Retrofit. It's the de-facto standard networking library these days. https://square.github.io/retrofit/
To put your authtoken into the header with retrofit, you have to add an HttpInterceptor. It's quite easy and you find a lot of examples when googling for it.